# Should I avoid identically named local variables?

Tags: c

Related - [naming convention of temp local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362063/naming-convention-of-temp-local-variables)

The answer to that question says local variables should have concise names. Would it be a problem if my local variables (in different functions) have identical names? E.g.

```
int foo(void){
 int counter;
 do stuff with counter;
}

int bar(void){
 int counter;
 do stuff with counter;
}

int main(void){

 foo();
 bar();
 foo();

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: whatever floats your boat. If you're comfortable knowing exactly what scope a variable has, you're fine. If you have a hard time remembering, that each `counter` ceases to exist after the function terminates, then use different names. The compiler won't care :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with identically named variables declared in different functions.  Their scope is the function itself. If that were an issue it would make programming a lot more of a PITA.  We'd run out of loop variable names very quickly.

Comment: Took me a moment but I eventually expanded PITA.

Answer (score 0):

No, the scope of your `counter` variables is limited to the block where they have been declared. Note that it is pretty common to use for example the same name `i` for a loop variable in different functions.

Answer (score 0):

No. Conceptually, functions enclose different tasks/scopes. There may be a need for two similarly named local variable since its functionality may be the same. It's not a technical nor a conceptual problem. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same name for local variables since their scope is limited to the block..

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's not a problem.

Using names that makes sense for what the code does is the best way to make sure other people understand your code. If you have a bunch of functions that do something similar (e.g. operates on the same data fetched via some common function), it is definitely a good idea to name that variable the same way in all the functions. That way, someone who knows how one of the functions work, will be able to understand what is going on with the same thing in the next function, etc.